# What is "the Halachic State"?

Tags: politics-government, state-of-israel, sanhedrin

There is a term called מְדִינַת הֲלָכָה - Halachic State. On Wikipedia (not a reliable source, but could not find anything else), it says:

> A Halachic State is a Jewish state that endorses Judaism in an official capacity and derives most or all aspects of governance from halakha

Where did this term come from and has it any backing up in sources of halacha? Are there even poskim or other sources that discuss this term and the meaning behind it and what the requirements are to be a halachic state?

The reason why I ask, is because I was baffled about something I read on how the Knesset works.  Refer to [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/147894/p/106/t/0.80609398103694611234/fs/rmxLEerulVRnMsGWsEA8aLS042HHxvtl53PDsj2CuASp/start/0/end/70/c):

> אפילו יהי' חוק הגוקר כל התורה כולה אם תקבל הסכמת הרוב הרי זה יתקבל לחוק כי בפירוש הותנה הרבה פעמים שאין המדינה מדינת הלכה רק מדינת חוק

Comment: I mean biblical  israel was a theocracy, a halachic state would be a theocratic Jewish state that enforces Halacha. Some examples of this can include prohibition of certain sexual relations forbidden by Halacha, prohibition of production of non kosher meat and food, prohibition of electricity generation on Shabbat and Yom tov, and subsidizing of religious articles like teffilin, mezuzot, and tallit @shmuel I don’t know when it started although it was probably popularized by religious Zionists like Abraham Isaac kook ZT”L and meir kahane ZT”L

Comment: What do you find baffling about that quote?

Comment: That, even when a law is against the Torah, if the majority is in favor of it, it passes the knesset. It says it is not a state of halacha.

Comment: Of course. It's fundamentally a secular state.